# Is there an more efficient transpose in a Pandas DataFrame than what I am doing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I am working with a data set like this:

```
a = {'SERVER':['SERVA','SERVB','SERVC','total'],'TAG':[5,10,15,25]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

The output I want is to have the items in 'SERVER' become the column names, with the corresponding values of Tag placed below them.

I am doing this:

```
    df_c = df.transpose()
    df_c.reset_index(drop = True,inplace=True)
```

Which outputs of:

```
       0      1      2      3
0  SERVA  SERVB  SERVC  total
1      5     10     15     25
```

Then I want to drop the column index(I think?, The row of numbers above SERVA, SERVB, etc) and make row 0 the column names:

```
df_c=df_c.rename(columns =df_c.iloc[0])
df_c=df_c[1:]
df_c.reset_index(inplace = True,drop = True)
```

Output:

```
  SERVA SERVB SERVC total
0     5    10    15    25
```

This is what I want.  Is there a more efficient/cleaner way of doing this? I think I am missing a detail of Transpose, but I am scratching my head of a way to do this is fewer lines or a more "pythonic" way.

Thanks!

PS:
My Original method was to take everything apart and reassemble it into a new DataFrame.  It is shown so you can see how I got to Transpose.

```
col_list = [str(x) for x in df['SERVER']]
val_list = [x for x in df['TAG']]
new_dict = {}
for c,v in zip(col_list,val_list):
    list1 = [v]
    new_dict[c]=list1
df_b = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

First [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) on the column which you want as a column, then use [`.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) to transpose:

```
In [403]: df.set_index('SERVER').T
Out[403]: 
SERVER  SERVA  SERVB  SERVC  total
TAG         5     10     15     25
```

**OR:**

```
In [413]: df.set_index('SERVER').transpose()
Out[413]: 
SERVER  SERVA  SERVB  SERVC  total
TAG         5     10     15     25
```